# Draw html on image using ImageMagick

Tags: html, imagemagick

Are there possibility to draw html string as text on image using imagemagick?

I'm not going to use divs or other tags, but it would be awesome to be able to draw text with bold, italic etc tags.

The idea to have wysiwyg editor with just b,i,u options and be able to draw this text in same formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there possibility to draw html string as text on image using imagemagick?

Of course.

```
echo '<html><body><strong>Hello</strong> <em>world</em></body></html>' | convert - /tmp/out.png
```

**But** I believe what you really want is a limited set of markup to influence drawing style of text. This is the `pango:` protocol as described [in the usage documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#pango_markup).

> For example..
>
> ```
> convert -background lightblue -gravity center -size 180x \
>       pango:"The <b>bold</b> and <i>beautiful</i>" \
>       pango_formatting.gif
> ```

[image]

Comment: having problems with pango install, I see PANGO* PANGO     --- which mean it does not installed properly or something. But I belive it works as you examples from official docs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right place

Comment: I hope you don't mind my adding a picture to illustrate.